# persisting json array data

Tags: json, angularjs

I've been working with AngularJS and JSON for a while now, and I am currently writing a simple todo app that uses the following array to store its todos:

```
$scope.todos = [    

    // todo 1
    {
        title:  'Personal',
        status: 'todo',
        // categories for todo 1
        categories: [
            {
                title:  'Shopping', 
                status: 'doing',
                // items for category 1, todo 1
                items: [
                    {
                        title:  'Buy bacon',
                        status: 'complete',
                    },
                    {
                        title:  'Buy tuna',
                        status: 'doing',
                    },
                ], // / items
            },
        ], // /categories
    },
]; // todos
```

So far, so well. Now what I am not sure about is how to actually store this data permanently. If I use my application to add or modify a todo, it's all nice and good until I close the browser window and it's all back to the default values (obviously).

Until now, I have always been working with MySQL databases to store relational data. But I was wondering if there is a better way to store this json data?

I was thinking to create a simple php page with saves the whole array to a textfile. But that would mean rewriting the whole file every time I make even the tiniest change to the data.

I've heard there were databases available that allow you to store this type of data, but I don't know where to start? Any pointer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest going with a framework like [restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) to define your relations, you will then be able to use all kinds of noSQL databases which have a RESTfull JSON API such as couchdb or mongodb etc.
It uses promises which is nice future proof and modern, it also supports all HTTP methods you might need, but it has a lot more features than that, take a look at the repo's [readme](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular).

Here is also a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/d6yDka?p=preview) which uses [mongolabs](https://mongolab.com), mongodb flawored cloud service.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing keeps you from saving this in a relation database like MySQL, you could have entities like a Todo, Category and Item, then serialize then into JSON and serve them RESTfully.

I think what you were looking for is a NoSQL database. They can store JSON data natively and can store chunks of data instead of just rows of data like traditional relational databases.

Two popular NoSQL databases are

- [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)
- [RethinkDB](http://www.rethinkdb.com)